# Using data from another workbook (other than the active one)

Tags: excel, vba

Ignoring what my code actually does (it's not important to my question):

I want to be able to open my excel file, press a button, have the code use data in that workbook and another opened workbook (so I would have two workbooks opened at the same time, the macro runs in one of them but can take data from both of them).

The trick here is that I can't seem to find code to access the other workbook that I've opened up, so I can only take info from the active workbook.

For example,

```
Private Function GetLastRow() As Integer

Dim myLastRow As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

myLastRow = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

GetLastRow = myLastRow

End Function
```

This code lets me access the active workbook (the one running the code), using ThisWorkbook.

Is there another function capable of allowing me to access another opened workbook?

Comment: Yes - I suggest reading up on using workbooks as variables.  [This page should help](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-workbook/), or any of [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+refer+to+open+workbook) should get you going.  You're getting there, with the `Set ws = ...` line.  However, when you call a naked `Range()`, that runs on whatever the ActiveSheet is.  If you want to make sure that the `Range()` refers to a range on the `Sheet1` worksheet, then simply do `myLastRow = ws.Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks for the link I was able to find a useful feature, 'ActiveWorkbook'. But I don't think this ever reads an active book other than the one I click the button in (so it would never access the other workbook I want to draw data from).

Comment: Note that row counting variables **must** be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. So both, your function *and* your variable must be declared `As Long`. • I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function to be more flexible.

```
Private Function GetLastRow(InWorksheet As Worksheet, InColumn As Variant) As Long
    GetLastRow = InWorksheet.Cells(InWorksheet.Rows.Count, InColumn).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

So you can call it …

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = GetLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1"), "C") 'column as letter
    'or
    'LastRow = GetLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1"), 3)  'column as number

End Sub
```

So you can even run this on another workbook using:

```
LastRow = GetLastRow(Workbooks("OtherWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheet("Sheet1"), "C") 'column as letter
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Workbook object built into VBA that you can use. This documentation should give you the information that you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook

You would simply put the name of your other workbook in quotes, in parentheses after using the Workbook object (see example on page I hyperlinked). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is definitely a useful feature but do you know if there's a way to access the other workbook if you don't know its name?

Comment: If you don't know the other workbook's name then you can loop over the open workbooks `For Each wb in Application.Workbooks` and select the first instance where `wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you looking for.
When you have more then one Workbook active you can switch between then.

```
Sub GetLastRow()

Dim myLastRow As Integer

'Active Workbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
myLastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox myLastRow


'Way when you know workbook name
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Teste1.xlsx"
Set ws1 = Application.Workbooks("Teste1.xlsx").Sheets("Plan1")
myLastRow1 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox myLastRow1

Dim myLastRow As Integer

'If you don't know the name but, opened after your main Workbook
Set ws3 = Application.Workbooks(2).Sheets("Plan1")
myLastRow3 = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox myLastRow3

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that row counting variables **must** be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. So both, your function *and* your variable must be declared `As Long`. • I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.